# Why does a `continue` in a match arm not have to typecheck?

Tags: types, rust

[Rust's guessing game tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html) has the following example code:

```
let guess: u32 = match guess.trim().parse() {
    Ok(num) => num,
    Err(_) => continue,
};
```

The result of the match should be `u32` and this is the case in the `Ok(num)` branch. However, the `Err(_)` branch returns `continue`, which is certainly not a `u32`. Why does this typecheck and work?

Answer (score 8):

> However, the `Err(_)` branch returns `continue`

Not really. `continue` is not something that "returns", it's something that changes the flow of code. Since that match arm does not produce a value, the type of it doesn't matter. The `match` as a whole does typecheck - every *resulting value* is a `u32`.

You can also use other control flow keywords like `return` or `break`.

A similar concept is [divergent functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082098/155423). These are functions that are guaranteed to **never** return, so they can be used in place of *any* expression.

This allows you to also use macros like `panic!("...")` or `unimplemented!()` as a match arm, as these expand to a diverging function.

Comment: Note: much as divergent functions return `!` (bottom) it is useful to consider `return x`, `break` and `continue` as expressions evaluating to `!`. Then, since bottom is [a subtype of all types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type#Computer_science_applications), it is natural for it to convert to `u32` (or any type, really).