# Can I use the question mark operator (?) in a divergent function that returns the never type (!)?

Tags: rust

I'm writing Rust for an embedded project and my `main` function's signature is

```rust
#[entry]
fn main() -> !
```

I understand that this means that it will never return, and I generally enter an infinite loop at the end of main.

I want to use the `?` try operator in my main function, but I couldn't search the docs for `rust ? in !`. How do I spell this out in words?

Can I use `?` in a `() -> !` function?

Comment: `?` *returns from the enclosing function*, and `!` is the return type of a function that *never returns*. Wouldn't using `?` in a function returning `!` lead to a contradiction of sorts?

Comment: On searching: unless things are drastically different in the nightly, `?` uses `From` trait. `!` itself is called a "never type". [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html), [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35121).

Comment: It is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question as well as others hunting for one of your questions. I've focused your question on the specifics of using `?`. The other aspect of your question is covered in [Why would I use divergent functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082098/155423) and [Why does Rust have a “Never” primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51832396/155423).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can I use `?` in a `() -> !` function

No. The `?` operator is an expression where `X?` is interpreted roughly as:

```
match X {
    Ok(success_value) => success_value,
    Err(err_value) => {
         return Err(err_value);  // returns from the enclosing function
    }
}
```

Note how the `?` expression implies a *return* from the function that uses it. For `X?` to compile, the function's return type needs to be a `Result` whose error variant is compatible with the error variant of `X`. A function that returns the never type `!` specifically promises never to return, so its return type is not compatible with the `return` implied by the `?` operator.

A function that never returns should either handle error results using `match` or equivalent to choose the appropriate action, or call `.unwrap()` or `.expect()` to convert them into panic.

Comment: I know you said "roughly", but it's worth observing that the `?` operator doesn't *only* work with `Result`, but with any type that implements [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html). (This is different from the `try!` macro, which *does* only work with `Result`.)

Comment: @trentcl Indeed, that's why I used "roughly"; even the old `try!` macro was more elaborate than the approximation, because it used `From` to convert between compatible error types. Do you know where in the docs one can find the precise semantics of `?`?

Comment: No, I think there is some hangup about the (non-)stabilization of `Try` (although the fact that `Result` and `Option` both work with `?` *is* stable since 1.22, the existence of the `Try` trait itself is still unstable.) There is, of course, the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0243-trait-based-exception-handling.md), but the description there is not exactly what has been accepted (`catch` expressions are not, and the `Try` trait is called `ResultCarrier` with a slightly different API).

Comment: @trentcl At first that looked like a documentation bug - unstable features are still documented, e.g. `Try`. But `?` itself is an operator, and operators aren't documented in the stdlib docs - it's not like you can find the documentation for `+` or `&mut` (as far as I know). Perhaps the [description of `?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) in the book could be expanded, or at least fixed not to claim that the function must return `Result` in order to use `?`.