# Avoid "use of possibly uninitialized variable" in "match" structure which is unreachable when variable is undefined in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm writing a console Rust application. It takes its first argument and decides which mode to run in. If the first argument is undefined or unknown, the application should exit. Here is the code:

```
use std::env;
use std::process;

enum RunMode {
    Extract,
}

fn die_with_error(error: &str) {
    eprintln!("{}", &error);
    process::exit(-1);
}

fn main() {
    let mut args = env::args();
    args.next();
    let mut runmode;

    match args.next() {
        Some(arg) => {
            match arg.as_ref() {
                "extract" => runmode = RunMode::Extract,
                _ => die_with_error(&format!("Unknown mode {}", &arg.to_string())),
            };
        }
        None => die_with_error("No mode specified. Please specify a mode as a first argument. Use --help to get a list of modes available"),
    };

    match runmode {
        RunMode::Extract => {
            let file_name = args
                .next()
                .expect("Please specify a filename as a second argument");
            println!("You passed {}", file_name);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile and produces the following error:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly uninitialized variable: `runmode`
  --> src/main.rs:27:11
   |
27 |     match runmode {
   |           ^^^^^^^ use of possibly uninitialized `runmode`
```

I understand there are situations when the runmode can be undefined, but in these situations the line 27 with `match` won't ever be reached.
I am able to avoid by defining a default value for runmode, but this doesn't seem clean. What is the proper way to deal with this in Rust?

Comment: See also [Why would I use divergent functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082098/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the compiler's point of view, when you call `die_with_error()`, your function doesn't return any value to the caller. In actuality, this function doesn't only return nothing, it doesn't return at all. The way to express this in Rust is with the [never type `!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.never.html):

```
fn die_with_error(error: &str) -> ! {
    eprintln!("{}", &error);
    process::exit(-1)
}
```

With this change, the compiler will know that `runmode` must always have an initialized value.