# How to print Error from a Result the right way

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'am trying to connect db to query data,
I want to print the error instead of panicking here this is what I tried:

```
let ConnectionResult = tokio_postgres::connect(
    "host=localhost user=postgres password=123456 dbname=postgres",
    NoTls,
)
.await;

let (client, connection) = match ConnectionResult {
    Ok(connection) => connection,
    Err(e)=> {
        eprintln!("ERRor {}", e);
    }
};

// The connection object performs the actual communication with the database,
// so spawn it off to run on its own.
tokio::spawn(async move {
    if let Err(e) = connection.await {
        eprintln!("connection error: {}", e);
    }
});

let Queryresult = client
    .query("select * from mock_data", &[])
    .await;

let rows = match Queryresult {
    Ok(rows) => rows,
    Err(e)=> {
        eprintln!("query Error, {}", e);
    }
};

for row in rows {
    println!("{:#?}", row.get::<usize, String>(0));
}
```

But the compiler complains with

```
let (client, connection) = match ConnectionResult {
   |                                ---------------------- `match` arms have incompatible types
18 |         Ok(connection) => connection,
   |                           ---------- this is found to be of type `(Client, Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>)`
19 |         Err(e)=> {
20 |             eprintln!("ERRor {}", e);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `(Client, Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>)`, found `()`
```

How should I write it?

Comment: Does this with it's linked duplicates answer your question? [Why can't I use println! to handle an error in a match statement but panic! works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225245/why-cant-i-use-println-to-handle-an-error-in-a-match-statement-but-panic-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you would get an invalid value if the error was just printed without aborting the program. You need to either provide a default value or interrupt the control flow. You can also add additional checks to make sure this just never panics. Without seeing the full code and understanding the very purpose of this app, I assume that aborting the execution is just the right way.

If your problem is about panic messages being simply too ugly, you might want to insert a call to `std::process::abort` after printing the error or use `std::panic::set_hook` in the beginning of your program.

Side note: Matching results isn't always a good pattern. You apparently can use `unwrap_or_else` in this case, if you aren't planning to interrupt the control flow via some operator.

Comment: ah yes I get it now, I just need to add `return;` after `eprintln!` then it pass the complier check all I missing is to interrupt the control flow
thank you , first time work with Result make my head spinning :D

Answer (score 1):

The `match` arms have different types. One possible solution is to avoid the `match`:

```
let (client, connection) = ConnectionResult;
let Ok(connection) = connection else { eprintln!("ERROR {}", connection.err().unwrap()); return; };
```

The `let-else` construct used was introduced in Rust 1.65 and can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html).